# Prepend to URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Apologies if this question has been asked or I'm not sure if the title is correct, but I have just started to work with htaccess files and I am a bit lost. Basically what I want to do is prepend "index.php" to the URL. For example, if a user enters:

http://www.example.com/show/12

I would like the htaccess file to make the URL:

http://www.example.com/index.php/show/12

If that is not possible, is there a way to always go to the index.php front controller and add the "show/*number*" to the URL, so that the front controller can pass the parameters to another controller?

My htaccess code is the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

I need it to assume that all URL requests are going to index.php front controller, then pass the rest of the URL to the front controller.

The error I keep getting is:

```
The requested URL /testing-mod-rewrite/show/12 was not found on this server.
```

Here is my PHP code for the front controller if it helps:

```
include_once('controllers/baseController.php');
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urifinal = str_replace($uri , '/', $uri);

$request = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$controller = new BaseController();
$controller->index_action($request);
```

Comment: Why would you want users to see `index.php/` in the url? Most developers would want to hide this.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to have that in the URL, I want to hide it and allow the htaccess file to always go to the index.php front controller and the rest of the URL is passed to index.php.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the current htaccess? Looks fine to me

Comment: It keeps saying "The requested URL /testing-mod-rewrite/show/12 was not found on this server."

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /testing-mod-rewrite`. Also make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled, and adding a RewriteBase did not work either. Disabled and enabled mod_rewrite again as well as restarting Apache, nothing.

Comment: You should put the error message already into your question, because without it, it's not clear what the concrete problem is you run in. Also please take a look into the error.log of the webserver, which URL was not found exactly (404 error). Additionally you can enable the rewrite logging and see what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi hakre, thanks for your response. I will look into the logs now, just need to figure out where they are on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, shouldn't take long to find.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Actually, I'm not entirely sure what you want. In your question you say you want to add index.php to the url if it does not have it. In a comment under your question, you say you want to remove it from the URL. The former would most likely be significantly easier using PHP. The latter should be accomplished by the following:

---

You could pass in the information to a query string.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

So the entered URL could be like: example.com/view/test/foo and the rewritten (internal) URL would be example.com/index.php?view=test/foo

Now in the PHP you should be able to do:

```
$view = $_GET['view'];
$controller = new BaseController();
$controller->index_action(explode('/', $view));
```

Note that you should validate the input contained in $view at some point.

EDIT: Also, I don't get this line:

```
$urifinal = str_replace($uri , '/', $uri);
```

It seems to be an over-complicated way of saying:

```
$urifinal = '/';
```

Unless I'm completely missing something.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your response. I will give your code a go and see how it goes. As for the $urifinal variable, I was using this for testing purposes, and redirecting to other directories just to try something out.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Here is an example that redirects the entered URL:

`http://www.example.com/show/12` To this URL:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?show=12`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(show)/([0-9]+)/?$ http://www.example.com/index.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

I am aware that is not exactly the answer to the question, but for your question to work as it is, you need to create a subdirectory with the name `index.php` and I don't think that's possible.

Using any other name (new_dir, for example) the rule will be like this, provided the directories exist:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(show)/([0-9]+)/?$ http://www.example.com/new_dir/$1/$2 [L]
```

Last line will redirect to:

`http://www.example.com/new_dir/show/12`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Unfortunately this isn't working, I think I have tried this already.

Comment: @kibria3: I had not tested but when I tried to do it found a subdirectory called `/index.php/`. ¿Is that really what you want? Shouldn't be something like `/index.php?show=12`?

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/redirect-index-blog-root.html

Or if you own a wordpress site ,it is bit easy.
You need to install any of these plugins in your external\local site and follow the instructions in links to work.

1.) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

2.) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

3.) http://www.dailyblogtips.com/gocodes-url-redirection-plugin-for-wordpress/

4.) http://pathanruet.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/wordpress-plugin-url-redirection/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I have tried the askapache website, and this isn't working. I am creating everything from scratch, I would use something like WordPress or Symfony, but I have been told not to rely on any existing framework/cms.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seemed like my htaccess code was fine, all I needed to do was disable MultiViews.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes MultiViews + FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```